# Aggregate Function on an Expression Containing A Subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery, case, aggregate-functions

With the following t-sql query:

```sql
select u.userid
into #temp
from user u
where u.type = 1;

select top 50
    contentid,
    count(*) as all_views,
    sum(case when hc.userid in (select userid from #temp) then 1 else 0 end) as first_count,
    sum(case when hc.userid in (40615, 40616) then 1 else 0 end) as another_count
from hitcounts hc
inner join user u on u.userid = hc.userid
group by hc.contentid
order by count(*) desc;
```

I get an error message

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

However, if just include the column 'another_count' (with the hard-coded list of identifiers), everything works as I expected.  Is there a way I should go about only getting the count for userids contained within a subquery?  I plan to have multiple columns, each counting up a set/subquery of different userids.

Performance is not a concern at this point and I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: In most cases you can replace subquery with `left join` and do conditional aggregation. But for your query @GordonLinoff's answer is more straightforward and simple way.

Comment: @astentx Generally, I would always put a `CASE WHEN EXISTS... THEN 1 END` inside an `APPLY` and count that, because otherwise you may get incorrect results due to multiple rows coming out of the join.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a temporary table for this purpose.  Just use a conditional aggregation:

```
select top 50 contentid,
       count(*) as all_views,
       sum(case when u.type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as first_count,
       sum(case when hc.userid in (40615, 40616) then 1 else 0 end) as another_count
from hitcounts hc join
     user u
     on u.userid = hc.userid
group by hc.contentid
order by count(*) desc;
```